# How can a package's license be determined using OPKG package manager?

Tags: package-management, embedded, angstrom, licenses, opkg

OPKG is used as the package manager in an embedded Linux system.  I would like to be able to determine the license of a package prior to installing the package.  Is there a simple way to achieve this through the package manager (or related utility included with the Angstrom distribution)?

Alternatively, can the package manager list the license(s) of an installed package?